# Ptolemy reset GeoServer when I restarted the server

Tags: geoserver

Sorry for the strange title but it was the most appropriate description I could think of.

When I made some changes to allow GeoServer to connect to MS SQL Server then restarted the server it seems to have reset GeoServer's settings to something strange.

The admin password changed to something unknown to me (and it is hashed in the users.xml file).

The GeoServer now "belongs to The Ancient Geographers" and the administrator email changed to claudius.ptolomaeus@gmail.com (i.e. Ptolemy).

Has anyone come across this before? Even better does anyone know his password?

Comment: I suspect this could be because I am not running GeoServer as a service but I could have sworn that Ptolemy was not the original administrator when I first installed GeoServer.

Comment: did you forget to set the DATA_DIRECTORY environment variable?

Comment: Hi Ian, I was using the default path so I was not aware I needed to set it. Thanks for the heads up. I have explicitly set it and will see if that makes the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you moved your data directory to some other location and made your changes. On reboot you have not reset the environment variable (or web.xml) to point to the new directory. So GeoServer has either gone back to the default or recreated the default directory for you.

If this is the case the password is `geoserver`.

Comment: Thank you Ian. What you say sounds correct because although I did not move the data directory in adding some SQL Server extensions I copied over various DLLs and I also set up an environmental path so I can shutdown GeoServer using the shell if I want to.